# How to mount Dynamic disk's partition on Ubuntu?

Tags: disk, partitioning

I am using Ubuntu alongside of Windows. I have two HDD. 1st one is a Basic disk, on which Ubuntu and Windows are installed.
[image: BASIC DISK]

And 2nd one is a Dynamic disk. On which all my data has been stored.
Now the problem is I can't mount my Dynamic disk to Ubuntu.

[image: Dynamic Disk]

Please someone help me !!

Comment: To handle MS dynamic disks (LDM) you might have to use `ldmtool` (see e.g.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Disks,  https://wiki.a.at/blog/2013/02/18/ldmtool-accessing-microsoft-windows-dynamic-disks-from-linux/ or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/ldmtool.1.html

Answer (score 4):

Seems this questioned might be answered, but I thought I'd offer how I did this for my LDM disk.

You can use ldmtools to handle Microsoft dynamic disks. read more about ldmtools here:

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html

`sudo apt-get install ldmtool`

find the uuid of your dynamic disk, you can do this with `sudo blkid`

then mount the disk with `ldmtool create volume <uuid> <volume-name>`

fill the angle brackets with the uuid from blkid and choose a volume name, obviously don't include the angle brackets with the command.

Then are many ways to integrate that command to get the disks to mount on start up. There are many other posts regarding this.