# Does ldmtool work properly for windows mirrored drives?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I'm dual booting windows 10 with ubuntu. My windows installation has a 4 TB mirrored drive that I'd like to mount in linux as well. I read that `ldmtool` is the proper way to do this (according to https://askubuntu.com/a/1224873/910097), but when reading the manpage it left me wondering if `ldmtool` actually works or not.

I have a couple of questions:

What does the manpage mean when it says:

> Although a filesystem can be mounted read-write and its contents modified, ldmtool is not able to modify the LDM metadata itself. That is, it cannot create, remove or edit dynamic disks.

Does this mean it will not mirror the drives like it's supposed to once I mount them?

Does it mean that the drive is readonly when it's mounted?