# Problem with NTFS disk

Tags: hard-drive, windows, ntfs

I have HDD disk with two NTFS partitions, which I created in Windows 10, but Ubuntu sees only one. Disks utility shows both partitions as one.

Disk model: ST2000DM008-2FR102

**Windows 10 is on a different disk**

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 73,9 MiB, 77492224 bytes, 151352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 240,51 MiB, 252190720 bytes, 492560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 97,71 MiB, 102453248 bytes, 200104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 11,2 MiB, 11747328 bytes, 22944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 496,98 MiB, 521121792 bytes, 1017816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 91,69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 10,52 MiB, 11026432 bytes, 21536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 1,82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM008-2FR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4C943EA5-B9A8-45A4-A513-8177075DD757

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     34       2081       2048    1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sda2   2082      32767      30686   15M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3  32768 3907029134 3906996367  1,8T Microsoft LDM data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 223,57 GiB, 240056327680 bytes, 468860015 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A0719CCE-0ECA-49F7-8B14-BEB2C372533A

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3     239616 365398015 365158400 174,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  467798016 468856831   1058816   517M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb5  365398016 467798015 102400000  48,8G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop8: 40,86 MiB, 42840064 bytes, 83672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 452 KiB, 462848 bytes, 904 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
  
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: @waltinator Fast boot is already disabled

Comment: @karel No. Windows on different disk

Comment: @rusty I updated question

Comment: You have it as a LDM partition where you would have to mount it by using some sort of LDM tool.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/869770/how-to-mount-dynamic-disks-partition-on-ubuntu

Comment: See if [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/how-to-fix-partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary-warning) is of any help.

Comment: Also refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227009/my-ntfs-partitions-are-being-showed-as-ldm-data-partitions).

Comment: Microsoft has no undo to LDM. Some Windows tools also do not work with LDM. It was an old work around for the 4 primary partition limit on MBR partitioning, but with gpt now, no reason to use it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227285/how-can-i-mount-a-microsoft-ldm-partition-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-desktop Other options also Aomei or even testdisk if only 4 dynamic partitions:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv
& https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758